# langchain - cannot import name 'SQLDatabase' from langchain (python)

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

after installing:

```
pip install langchain-experimental
```

Hi I have tried:

```
from langchain_experimental.sql_database import SQLDatabase
```

but it does not work.

The code is as follows:

```
# 1. Load db with  langchain
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:////python/chatopenai/ecommerce.db")

# 2. Import APIs
import a_env_vars
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = a_env_vars.OPENAI_API_KEY

# 3. Create LLM
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0,model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')

# 4. Create chain
from langchain import SQLDatabaseChain
cadena = SQLDatabaseChain(llm = llm, database = db, verbose=False)
```

and the error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLDatabaseChain' from 'langchain' (C:\Users\jcarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\__init__.py) Traceback: File "C:\Users\jcarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\python\chatOpenAI\c_front_end.py", line 3, in <module>
    import b_backend File "C:\python\chatOpenAI\b_backend.py", line 15, in <module>
    from langchain import SQLDatabaseChain
```

and this is only after doing the same with langchain.sql_database
anyone clould heplp please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use this code:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///Chinook.db")
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(OpenAI(), db)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should update your library "langchain" ? You can update it using 'pip install --upgrade langchain'. Or delete and then download the new version of langchain. It can be an error when you have download that library or because your version is not the last one.

Comment: thank you- I just deleted the library langchain and  install again and the error persist.